# php remove one item from array

Tags: php, arrays

Say I have an array:

```
$before = array(1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5)
```

How would I remove just one occurence of eg '3' ?

```
$after = array(1,2,3,4,4,4,5)
```

(I don't know where in the array that number will be)

Comment: if you need an answer specific for this case, it'll be different than general case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a variety of methods, depending on what exactly you're trying to do:

- Find the index using `array_search()` and then `unset()` it.
- If you know the index, use `array_splice()` to replace it with nothing.
- Use `array_filter()` with a custom callback.

Comment: For example: unset($before[array_search(3,$before)]);. Removes the first occurrence of 3 in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Generic routine, just populate the $reduceValues array with the values you want reducing to singletons.

```
$before = array(1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5);

$reduceValues = array(3,5);
$toReduce = array_fill_keys($reduceValues,TRUE);
$after = array_filter( $before,
                       function($data) use ($reduceValues,&$toReduce) {
                           if (in_array($data,$reduceValues)) {
                               if ($toReduce[$data]) {
                                   $toReduce[$data] = FALSE;
                                   return TRUE;
                               }
                               return FALSE;
                           }
                           return TRUE;
                       }
                     );
var_dump($after);
```

Comment: @salathe - and there was me just working on a more generic version that would allow multiple "targets" to be reduced to a single entry.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the functionality you are looking for?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 0):

If you know the order of specific item you want to remove you can use something like

```
 unset $before[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do what you ask. Which one you should use depends on the context of its usage, as well as the exact result you desire. I prefer [array_splice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php), because it maintains the array numbering. If you want the easiest method, I suggest [unset()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php). If you are looking for a way to eliminate the dupes, use [array_unique()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php). With the latter two, if you need to renumber them back the way they were, use [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php). If you do not know the index of the value you need to remove, you can use one of the above in conjunction with [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php). If you need a more advanced filter, use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php).

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$original = array(1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5);

echo "ORIGINAL:\n";
print_r($original);
echo "\n\n";

echo "Using array_splice():\n";
$new = $original;
array_splice($new, 3, 1);
print_r($new);
echo "\n\n";

echo "Using array_unique() to remove dupes:\n";
$new = array_unique($original);
$new = array_values($new);
print_r($new);
echo "\n\n";

echo "Using unset:\n";
$new = $original;
unset($new[3]);
$new = array_values($new);
print_r($new);
echo "\n\n";

echo "Using array_search & unset:\n";
$new = $original;
unset($new[array_search('3', $new)]);
$new = array_values($new);
print_r($new);
echo "\n\n";
?>
```